# Can a single Web Domain have multiple passwords?

Tags: web-services, web

Just wanna know that is it possible for a single web domain to have multiple passwords?? It just came in my notice but I refused to accept that.. just wanna confirm this!!

Thanks!!

Comment: Your question is completely meaningless.  What on earth are you talking about?

Comment: why do you even need multiple passwords on one domain? educate us a little.

Comment: I am completely agree with you SLaks.. my client stated this.. and if you read the question carefully I wrote "I refused to accept that"

I didn't agree to him at all.. Instead of arguing with him I just wanted a proof to prove him wrong and stackoverflow is the best I.T. forum so that why I posted this question..!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this question was auto-corrected and is meant to be " is it possible for a single web domain to have multiple websites?"

If this is what is meant, the answer is yes. Multiple websites are achieved by using virtual hosts.

Comment: Thanks!!

Actually my client said that and I posted it as it is.. I was also shocked you read this but just wanna confirm it.. because we are living in the world of I.T. so I thought maybe it's possible some-how..

Comment: No worries. http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/vhosts/examples.html This is a good article for more information on setting up Virtual Hosts.